# Difficulty with \flalign

Tags: math-mode, formatting

Consider the following example.

```
\begin{flalign}
&Max Z=a+b\\
&Min P=c-d\\
&\mbox{subject to}\\
&a \leq 10\\
&c \geq 5
\end{flalign}
```

When I run it I get the desired output, but the only problem is I do not want "subject to" to get numbered. So if I modify it, and write something like

```
\begin{flalign}
&Max Z=a+b\\
&Min P=c-d
\end{flalign}
subject to
\begin{flalign}
&a \leq 10\\
&c \geq 5
\end{flalign}
```

then my alignment between the first set of equations and the second set of equations gets disturbed.

How do I proceed?

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use `flalign`, but `align`; use `\notag` in the “subject to” line.

Answer (score 6):

As @egreg said, use `align`. Also, with `mathtools` you can use `\shortintertext`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

   \begin{align}  
    \max  Z &=a+b\\  
    \min  P &=c-d\\  
    \shortintertext{subject to}
    a &\leq 10\\  
    c &\geq 5  
    \end{align}
```

Also, use `\min` and `\max`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest one of these this variant, using `llap`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
   \begin{align}
  \max Z &=a+b \\
   \min P &=c-d \\[1ex]
  \text{\llap{subject to: \hskip 2em}} a &\leq 10 \\
      c &\geq 5
     \end{align}

\begin{flalign}
 & & \max Z &=a+b & & \\
 & & \min P &=c-d \\[1ex]
 & \text{\rlap{subject to: }} & a &\leq 10 \\
 & & c &\geq 5
\end{flalign}
More text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like this variant, but with the subject correctly aligned to the left. I hope the “next version” of a basic math package includes something like `\shortintertext` but in the same line instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Look at my edit: with `flalign` one can do what you want, I think.

Comment: I know, but it's less “*robust*”, I mean, you have to think, to add `&`, it's less automatic.

Comment: That's true; however you have to put 5 `&` only in the first line, then only 3. I agree it would be a syntax simpler if we had a sort of `\intext` or `\leftag` command. Note that if your equation numbers were on the left, the `\tag` command would do the trick.